# Python NLTK unexpected for-cycle corpora data loss

Tags: python, for-loop, nltk

Not the most fond of python over here, but have to use it for NLTK. This is why I suspect I'm missing something simple.

I have a corpora that consists of articles, which consist of sentences.
I also have the following function:

```
unlabelled = [] #first word of a sentence
labelled = [] #all words of a sentence except the first
for article in corpora:
    for sent in article:
        print(list(sent)) #returns everything as it should be
        for i, w in enumerate(sent):
            if (i == 0): 
            unlabelled.append((w.lower(), w))
        else:
            labelled.append((w.lower(), w))
        print(list(sent)) #returns everything as it should be

for article in corpora:
    print(list(article)) #returns all empty
```

It should do nothing to the corpora data, just collect words from it to two lists. Within the cycles, printing the corpora data shows that it is all intact, nothing is changed. However, printing right after the cycle shows the corpora is suddenly empty, all articles are empty arrays and sentences no longer exist.

What is happening here and why?

Comment: did you try printing just article instead of list(article)

Comment: Not too familiar with NLTK or what kind of type `article` has but `print(list(sent))` is not the same as `print(list(article))`.

A list comprehension like `print([list(s) for s in article])` would be more in line to what you have in the first set of for-loops.

Comment: @ChetanVasudevan it returns generator object without the list() method, so I wouldn't be able to tell what data it holds.